# ios implement video share which loacate in Photos

Tags: ios

I use `UIActivityViewController` to implement eMail and Message.

```
NSArray *activityItems;
activityItems = @[[self.mURL path],self.mURL];
UIActivityViewController *activityController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                  applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController
                   animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But how can I implement below view, especially **youtube**, **youku**, and **tudou** on iOS6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will have to provide a custom UIActivity that handles URLs and file paths. For an example, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view

Look about halfway through that section, where I create a custom activity called Be Cool.

What you will actually do with the URL (i.e. how you are going to get this video sent to YouTube, or whatever it is you are trying to do) is entirely up to you.

Comment: thank you for your help. but the next questions is how can i use system api to sent video to YouTube